# Postfix не отправляются письма с сайта на внутренние адреса

Tags: postfix

Письма не уходят совершенно на внутренние адреса сайта. В логах /var/log/maillog ничего нет. В очереди письма оседают.
Уствновлен postfix-2.10.1-7.el7.x86_64
Cenyos 7 / Linux 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 1 14:54:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu

Comment: _В логах /var/log/maillog ничего нет_ не может быть. Постфикс отличается очень подробными логами

Comment: В момент отправки почты с сайта на собственный адрес (куда не приходят письма) в логи ничего не пишется. Другие все сообщения уходят без проблем